# Hyper-V core and Replica

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

So I have question I have been looking around for and havent been able to get solved.  We are thinking of replacing all of our servers and going virtual.  My question is if I user Hyper-V core on a host server can I still set it to replicate to another VM on a different host so that if host 1 were to go down host 2 picks up?

Comment: Searching for “hyper-v server high availability” or “hyper-v server cluster” turns up all sorts of relevant information. Are you sure you properly researched the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, hyper-v core (the free version) supports the feature 'hyper-v replica' .

But , hyper-v replica is not a High Available solution . Because 'data delay' can not be avoided when unplanned failover occurs ('planned failover' without this issue).

You may consider hyper-v cluster , using two or more physical hosts .

'hyper-v cluster':
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831579(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Yes but as already stated if you are talking HA then go with a cluster.  However, it's perfectly possible to VM your servers on hyper V and then replicate them for protection against hardware failure.

In my work we've done this - 3 servers, all workgroup machines and each are replicating their VM's around each other - ie. server1->server 2, server2->server3 and server3->server1. Replication time is set to 5 mins so at most we loose 5 mins or so worth of data.  Depending on your environment this may, or may not, be acceptable.  For us, it's ok - in this config we can loose an entire machine, but be back up and running in minutes by just failing over the replicas and starting them up on their new host.  We then need to fix the bust server, reverse replication and go back to how we used to be running.

It's a no brainer if cost is an issue - plus each physical server is using RAID as well so disk failures etc. don't affect things.  From my 25 odd years of experience I think short of spending bazillions in cash on a full on SAN (20K plus - practically name your price really) this is a pretty cost effective way of improving service reliability for a company.

The only thing you need to worry about really is getting the servers to talk to each other from a replication point of view.  You basically need to setup SSL so each server creates and signs it's own certificates - which are then trusted by the other servers.  Sounds like a pain but to be honest it's so simple I still can't believe it works.